# How would I place a three week workshop experience on a resume?

Tags: resume

I was lucky enough to be able to attend a paid three week workshop experience at a national laboratory with the intention to learn and develop introductory coding skills.

Where would I place this experience in a resume though? Would it be under internships? Or would I make up a new category?

Comment: under education

Comment: How much other stuff do you have on your resume, and what sections were you planning to include? If you're listing internships as a separate section I guess you're still in college, or a recent graduate?

Comment: internship / education / Special One of These three depending on what you Think the description fits most.

Comment: I feel silly for even asking now. Thank you all. It seems obvious when you all state it now.

Comment: You should put it under a section 'Training' as distinct from 'Education'.

Comment: @RoSiv As long as you have a genuine question and put a minimum of effort into the post (which includes looking for duplicates), there's really no harm in asking. We don't mind an easy question and it's human nature to sometimes miss the obvious when faced with a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the program.

If its main purpose was to teach you to code (I mean, teach you a technology skill that isn't related to the organization itself), then it looks like an educational program and should be in education, specifically in complimentary education, if you have such section in your resume.

But if you already have the coding skills and what you've done was work in organization's real world issues, to learn how to work there and/or have experience in the area, looks like it's more like an internship.

There's a third option. You said you were "lucky enough" for that. If lucky was used as an expression, but really meaning you were selected for that, among many people, for any technical reason, you could have an achievement section in your resume telling that.